# Tamaño de la vista igual al xib, que a su vez, tiene que ser igual a su contenido

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, constraints

He cargado un xib como vista en mi storyboard, para poder reutilizarlo siempre que me plazca. El problema es que no consigo adecuar su tamaño al tamaño del botón, que es el que me interesa.

Las medidas del botón sería: w=343, h=48.
El tamaño del xib no lo he especificado, simplemente lo he hecho un poco más pequeño de la vista que venía por defecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los constraints son para centrar el botón en el centro, y el ancho y alto del botón. Pero creo que me interesaría más que el xib cogiera el tamaño del botón ¿Cómo podría hacerlo? ¿Tengo que especificárselo manualmente al igual que el botón?

El código que utilizo para cargar la xib como view es:

```
func xibSetup() {
    guard let view = loadViewFromNib() else { return }
    view.frame = bounds
    view.autoresizingMask =
                [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    addSubview(view)
    contentView = view
}
```

Después he añadido la xib, como vista a mi storyboard, y ha quedado así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En resumen: Me gustaría que todo se adecuara al tamaño del botón, que es el que me importa.

Comment: Intenta sin  esta línea: view.autoresizingMask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existen dos formas para poder lograr esto la primera es poder definir intrinsicContentSize de tu vista

```
class MiVista: UIView {

   override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
     return CGSize(width: 343, height: 48)
   }

}
```

La otra es que al momento de agregar una vista como subvista esta por default tiene la propiedad

> translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints

encendida y por ende se utiliza Autoresize Mask para porder hacer grande o pequeños los elementos en pantalla. Puedes utilizarla pero te obliga a definir el frame antes de agregarla como subvista.

Cada que agreagas un elemento en pantalla y quieras utilizar contraints debes definirlas ya sea en el storyboard o meditante codigo si lo haces mediante codigo primero debes desabilitar la propiedad anterior y despues agregar como subvista y por ultimo agregar las constraints por codigo que pueden ser mediante el visual format, anchor o directamente constraint por constraint.

```
func xibSetup() {
    guard let view = loadViewFromNib() else { return }
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    addSubview(view)
    self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 343))
    self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 48))
    self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))

    contentView = view
  }
```